# LINQ Aggregate results with Many to Many Relationship

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am currently working with this schema
[image]

This is how my LINQ currently looks

```
var regionResults = (
                    from p in _context.Projects
                    from pr in p.Regions
                    where (data.RegionId == null || pr.RegionId == data.RegionId)

                    group p by pr.RegionId into g
                    join q in _context.Regions on g.Key equals _context.Regions.First().Id  
                    select new Models.ViewModels.ProjectBreakdownViewModel.Regions
                    {
                        RegionName = q.Name,
                        TotalCount = g.Count(),
                        RejectedCount = g.Count(e => e.SubmissionStatusId == 2),
                        DeniedCount = g.Count(e => e.SubmissionStatusId == 3)
                    });
```

this is what it is currently producing, albeit incorrect
[image]

This is what I need it to be...

[image]

I know the problem is with this line, essentially

```
join q in _context.Regions on g.Key equals _context.Regions.First().Id
```

I don't know how to do this without the use of .First(), there doesn't seem to be a way to do it.  I'm close I just don't know how to finish this.

Comment: what is "data" in where (data.RegionId == null || pr.RegionId == data.RegionId)
?

Comment: data is just an object being passed to the controller method, one of the params being passed via querystring as RegionId.  It should be to handle a null as well.

Comment: Do you have a `ProjectRegions` entity or it's implicit in you model?

Comment: I suppose it is both? It is explicitly defined because EF Core requires many-many tables to be defined.  There isn't a DbSet defined for it in context, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an collection of `ProjectRegions` in you `Region` entity, you can do this:

```
var result= context.Regions
                   .Where(r=> data.RegionId == null || r.Id == data.RegionId)
                   .Select(r=> new  
                               {
                                 RegionName = r.Name,
                                 TotalCount = r.ProjectRegions.Count(),
                                 RejectedCount = r.ProjectRegions.Count(e => e.Project.SubmissionStatusId == 2),
                                 DeniedCount = r.ProjectRegions.Count(e => e.Project.SubmissionStatusId == 3)
                               });
```

`ProjectRegion` entity should have two nav properties, `Project` and `Region`, use them to navigate and create the corresponding conditions

Comment: I'm going to remove the first solution because I would follow the second one. About the `RegionId` error, it's just to change the name for the real `Id`

Comment: Ah, that was my first question, if you have the `ProjectRegion` table represented in your model

Comment: So, the type of the collection in `Region` entity is `ProjectRegion`, right?

Comment: I'm going in the other direction, so `region.Projects` should be also a collection of `ProjectRegion`

Comment: Please sir, fix the name of the properties according how they are in your model, unfortunately I don't have your real model in order to create a query without typos. I guess is just change `ProjectRegions` by `Projects`